# Page loading to slow using datatables C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am trying to clean up some pages in my solution. The pages or tables load slower than i would like. I am using a view model and doing a Foreach on the page in a table and then using datatables to display. It seems that on the database side it loads each record 1 at a time and with 1000s of records it takes way to long to load. When i run the query in SQL it is instantly populated. I am looking for some help to clean the code up and see if there is anything here that can be changed to make it load faster. Since I am using the foreach in the page the DeferRender does not work. It does not matter to me if i use this or JavaScript, certainly server side coding is an option. In the controller the use of an array may work also but i do not know how to incorporate that with a view model. "db.Companys.ToArray();" works for pulling from the model but the ToArray doesn't work with a viewModel to my knowledge.

Below is my code.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = (from temp in db.TopLvlJobs
                    join serial in db.SerialNumbers on temp.TopLvlJob equals serial.TopLvlJob
                    select new TopLvlJobsViewModels
                    {
                        PartNumber = temp.PartNumber,
                        Description = temp.Description,
                        ExtDescription = temp.ExtDescription,
                        Drawing = temp.Drawing,
                        IsDelete = false,
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        UpgradeAvailable = temp.UpgradeAvailable,
                        TopLvlJob = temp.TopLvlJob,
                        SerialNumber = serial.SerialNumber

                    }).OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate);

        return View(data);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TopLvlJobsViewModels
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "TopLvlJob")]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string TopLvlJob { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Ext Description")]
    [Required]
    public string ExtDescription { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Part Number")]
    [Required]
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Drawing")]
    [Required]
    public string Drawing { get; set; }
    [UIHint("_IsStatus")]
    [Display(Name = "Upgrade Available ?")]
    [Required]
    public bool UpgradeAvailable { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDelete { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Serial")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public TopLvlJobs topsjobs { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Pdfupload { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SubJobs> SubJobs { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Upgrades> Upgrade { get; set; }
}
```

JavaScript on .CHTML page

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //var oTableMenuPermission = "";
    //oTableMenuPermission = 
    $("#SubJobsListTable").dataTable({
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "dom": 'lBfrtip',
        "buttons": [
            { extend: 'copyHtml5', exportOptions: { columns: ':visible' } }
            , { extend: 'excelHtml5', exportOptions: { columns: ':visible' } }
            , { extend: 'csvHtml5', exportOptions: { columns: ':visible' } }
            , { extend: 'pdfHtml5', exportOptions: { columns: ':visible' } }
            , { extend: 'print', exportOptions: { columns: ':visible' } }
            , 'colvis'
        ], columnDefs: [{ visible: false, targets: [3] }, { orderable: false, targets: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] }],
        "pageLength": 10,
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    });
    //table.buttons().container()
    //    .appendTo($('.col-lg-8:eq(0)', table.table().container()));
});
```

I can give you anything else needed, I didn't post the whole CHTML page due to length, however it is just a basic Foreach in a table View.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not clear if the delay is the query or time to populate the view.  Which driver is the connection string using?  The speed of the query is a function of the server and the amount of time to transfer the data.  Some drivers are faster than others.  So I can't tell right now what is causing the issue.

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure what you mean by driver. I believe it is the query or the way the query goes about it. I used profiler and viewed while it populates. It seems to query each record separately. I will post a snippet from profiler while it populates.

Comment: See top of following webpage : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure what i did before in profiler to see what i saw. I just started working back on this. However it appears that the batch is complete at the server before the page is fully loaded..

Comment: @jdweng I see now what you mean. I do not know what driver it is using. The connection is through Entity Framework and I do not think i have control over that. The only thing i have in the connection string is ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient".  This is in the Web.config.

Comment: Here is latest connection string. I delete previous link since it was from 2011.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

use IQueryable instead of IEnumerable and try

Querying data from a database, IEnumerable execute a select query on the server side, load data in-memory on a client-side and then filter data.
Querying data from a database, IQueryable execute the select query on the server side with all filters.

Comment: I am assuming that you are referring to the Model for SubJobs and Upgrades. This does not have any bearing on loading the TopLvlJobs view. I am using an IEnumerable in the View. Using a IQueryable in the view, I have read, is not a good idea. Honestly i would love to just use Stored Procedures, but I cannot find a way to have each record with the Edit, Delete, etc buttons in the table. Probably because MVC is built differently. I use stored procedures to save, edit, and delete records. It is clean and fast.